# UI-Bootstrap (Angular) getting it to work with i.e8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have my Angular JS app which is built with ui-bootstrap. For some reason it works ok with ie9 and above. But I just cant get one app partial to work. I am doing the following:

Doctype:

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
```

Scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

I am primarily using the accordian, I have also tried:

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
     <!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script>
    document.createElement('accordion');
    document.createElement('accordion-group');
    document.createElement('accordion-heading');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

No luck with this? It is just one partial that is not working with the Angular? 
But I can't see why?

UPDATE: So ui-bootstrap seems to be working fine, but it is my angular.js code. The partial I have got just does not seem to load angular everything has: {{example}}

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: my view that uses my controller, just does not load angular.js?

Comment: so you are not getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, but I am sure it is something todo with ui-bootstrap - I am using 1.2.5 angular, as this version is compatible with ie8, but ui-bootstrap needs angular 1.3 and above so what should I do?

Comment: So the problem is there. Try 1.3. Not supporting something anymore doesn't necessarily mean it won't work, just that it might not. If it doesn't work then try using a lower version of ui-bootstrap.